# What is the significance of the count parameter in Stream.Write/Read?

Tags: c#, stream, memorystream

If I use a buffer that is bigger than the count will the program only take the desired length from the buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the count is the maximum number of bytes to be read in a call to `Stream.Read`, or the exact number of bytes to be written in a call to `Stream.Write`.

Note that `Stream.Read` returns the *actual* number of bytes read, which may be less than requested, even if there may still be more data to read if you call `Read` again. A common mistake is to ignore the value returned from `Stream.Read`. There's no equivalent for `Stream.Write`, as that always writes all the data you've said to write (or throws an exception if it can't do so).

Comment: will it return less only when the count is larger than Stream.Length - Stream.position?

Comment: @Foxman: Not all streams *support* the idea of `Length` and `Position`... and even if they do, I wouldn't assume that there's any guarantee about how that interacts with `Stream.Read` unless the concrete class you're using makes that guarantee explicitly. The *only* implementation I'd make that assumption about is `MemoryStream`.